# How to populate saved card values in the stripe element?

Tags: stripe-payments, angular7

The requirement is to list the cards added by the customer and allow him to edit card details. Once customer edit card, then his card details should get auto filled in stripe element. I have used the ngx-stripe library.

How to set the stripe element values?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pre-fill sensitive inputs (card number, CVC, and expiration date) in Stripe Elements. This is by design for security reasons.

A better flow would be to allow a user to delete and add new cards rather than edit them.

See the fields of a Payment Method that you can update here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update

Comment: then whats the use case for on-session saved card?